# Spinnaker in Production

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker

I am thinking of using Spinnaker in production. I have a 796 node Kubernetes cluster (Local deployment using kubeadm tool). How do I integrate spinnaker with kubernetes

Answer (score 1):

Use Halyard to deploy Spinnaker in the kubernetes cluster. You can define the target k8s clusters in spinnaker. Create deployment pipeline and chose the k8s target where the deployment needs to be done.

go through the below ebook to understand how to do Continuous deployment using spinnaker
https://www.spinnaker.io/publications/ebook/

Answer (score 0):

Using Halyard directly for configuring Spinnaker is a bit annoying, especially with its RBAC system by Fiat.

I would suggest you to use manifest-based configuration, such as
[**Spinnaker-operator**](https://github.com/armory/spinnaker-operator/tree/master), it's pretty well [**documented**](https://docs.armory.io/continuous-deployment/overview), there are a lot of ways to [**override**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78087469/how-to-apply-custom-profiles-setting-to-spinnaker-to-make-it-deploy-with-one-com) some settings directly from manifest, and it is easier to maintain service after deployment.

I am currently using Spinnaker on our Production k8s environment, and I was configuring and deploying it via Spinnaker-Operator.