# How to apply custom profiles/setting to Spinnaker to make it deploy with one command?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, configuration, customization, spinnaker

I'm trying to deploy Spinnaker to k8s cluster using Halyard that running in Docker container. Thing is, I've configured all by using `hal` commands, but official docs says that there is a way to do it using custom profiles.

So, I've tried to create custom profiles, putted them into `.hal/${DEPLOYMENT}/profiles`, but when I use `hal deploy apply --deployment ...` - it's only copying my profiles without applying them.
This is the first problem.

Secondly, I've tried to configure all in those profiles, and run `hal deploy apply --deployment ...` expecting that Halyard will see that those files already exist, and he can use them, but it always fails saying me that `Persistant storage type is not configured!`.

I do not understand how can I prepare only custom files, and where to put them, so I can only use
`hal deploy apply`, and poof! Everything that was configured has been deployed!

Can you describe maybe where to put those files, and how to run deploy, using them? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

This one, for example, I've putted into `.hal/${DEPLOYMENT}/profiles/gate-local.yml`:

```
security:
  basic:
    enabled: true
  apiSecurity:
    overrideBaseUrl: https://<domain-api>
  uiSecurity:
    overrideBaseUrl: https://<domain-ui>
  authn:
    oauth2:
      enabled: true
      client:
        clientId: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        clientSecret: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        accessTokenUri: https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/token
        userAuthorizationUri: https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/auth
        scope: openid,email,profile,groups
      resource:
        userInfoUri: https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/userinfo
      userInfoMapping:
        email: email
        firstName: given_name
        lastName: family_name
        username: preferred_username
```

And here is an example of my `front50-local.yml` that always fails:

```
persistentStorage:
  persistentStoreType: s3
  s3:
    bucket: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    rootFolder: front50
    pathStyleAccess: true
    endpoint: https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    accessKeyId: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    secretAccessKey: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    enabled: true
```

And etc. It's working if I use Hal commands to configure, but again, I want to:

1. Start container with Halyard
2. Give him prepeared configs
3. `hal deploy apply`

- boom. Welcome to Spinnaker. Any ideas?

Comment: I didn't find a solution yet. However, I've spotted that Halyard working like a bit another way. Your hal commands configures config, and when you apply it, it parses into small files. So, I've decided to make all configurations in config file, and it worked a bit. I still wonder if there another way to do this, so question still actual. Also, I do wonder how to use Keycloak as authz provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I found kinda solution for my issue.
I do not use `front50-local.yml` for my configuration, it's clearly working with configuration in main `config` file.
But, met the problem with `roles` through OpenId.
Found a way to override it with `gate-local.yml`, It can be useful for someone:

I've passed this part in main `config`:

```
security:
  apiSecurity:
    overrideBaseUrl: https://domain-api.example
  uiSecurity:
    overrideBaseUrl: https://domain-deck.example
  authn:
    oauth2:
      enabled: true
      client:
        clientId: XXXXXXXX
        clientSecret: XXXXXXXX
        accessTokenUri: XXXXXXXX
        userAuthorizationUri: XXXXXXXX
      resource:
        userInfoUri: XXXXXXXX
      userInfoMapping: {}
      provider: OTHER
```

And this part in `gate-local.yml`:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    userInfoMapping:
      email: email
      firstName: given_name
      lastName: family_name
      username: username
      roles: groups
    client:
      scope: openid,email,profile,groups,roles
```

Note, that mapping can be different from described above.
Finally, this configuration passed successfully, and now I can see my roles passed from Keycloak at
`https://domain-api.example/auth/user`

About provider. Part in main `config`:

```
providers:
   kubernetes:
      enabled: true
```

And the rest of settings are in `clouddriver-local.yml`:

```
kubernetes
   accounts:
   - name: XXXXX
     context: XXXX
     providerVersion: V2
     kubeconfigContents: encrypted:k8s!n:secret_name!k:secret_value
     namespaces: [] #Access to ALL namespaces
     permissions:
        READ:
        - everyone
        WRITE:
        - group1
        - group2
        - group3
        EXECUTE:
        - the-same-way
        CREATE:
        - the-same-way
     requiredGroupMembership: # Member of what group you have to be to 
     - group1                 #have access to this account
     configureImagePullSecrets: true
     cacheThreads: 1
     dockerRegistries: []
   primaryAccount: XXXXXX
```

Although, I do use Spinnaker-operator for deployment in k8s. It's a little easier to deploy with it, not facing `hal` commands itself.
Seems like a solution for my question! Hope it will help someone!

**UPDATE:**

Now, when we have provided `roles`, we can use them to setup RBAC system for our applications, etc.:

1. Enable `authz` in main `config`, in `security` section after `authn` above like this:

```
   ......
   ......
   provider: OTHER
authz:
  enabled: true
```

2)Next setup must be configured in `fiat-local.yml`.

```
fiat.restrictApplicationCreation: true #Allows to restrict permissions
auth.permissions.provider.application: aggregate
auth.permissions.source.application.prefix: #Allows to work with
  enabled: true                          # applications prefixes
  prefixes:
  - prefix: "*" # All applications
    permissions:
      READ:
      - "group1"
      WRITE:
      - "group1"
      EXECUTE:
      - "group1"
      CREATE:
      - "group1"
```

Now, if you login with user that is member of `group1`, it will be allowed to see available applications, create and manage them.
If it will be user without membership in this group - It won't access anything, and won't be able to create applications!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).